# Upload to Aws elastic beanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services

I have a question about how to upload to aws elastic beanstalk

My file structure is blelow:

I have a  `virtualenv` folder.
and I create a folder name `project`. 
In project,there are two folders. one is djangoproject (a website) , the other is some python files run scrapy project .

I try upload before.It seems like if I use this method  [Deploying a Django Application](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_python_console.html) ,I have to upload a pure django project as a root folder,so that the aws can catch my files.

Please teach me how to upload these to AWS EB, is my structure correct? or give some good tutorial websites so I can move on.

```
> virtualenv 
    >bin
    >include
    >lib
    >doc
    >etc
    > project
        > requirements.txt
        > djangoproject
        > scrapy
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested the EC2 deployment, so i can't tell for the EB workflow, but you have to upload your Django App, not the entire virtualenv folder. The better is you use Git, you can host your files on BitBucket witch offers free private repos and then install Git on your EB instance and get it from Git. Here is a link to [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Python_django.html).

Comment: should I put the ````scrapy```` folder under the ````djangoproject```` folder?

Comment: scrapy contains what ?

Comment: some python files it will scrape some infomation, so I will also need to setting time to let those files scrapy

Comment: You only have to put your Django App without any additional code in bitbucket. Your Django app is the folder create by django-admin cmd.

Comment: If you are using it inside your Django App, you should put it inside the app folder at the same level as your manage.py.

Comment: you means my scrapy files can't deploy aws eb ?

Comment: Yes it can, in your Django app folder you should have `manage.py` and `appname` in the same level, all your Django app related code put it inside `appname`. that is it !